# Alguien conoce alguna API de bolsa

Tags: android, api, android-volley

Estoy buscando una API bursátil para consumir recursos para una aplicación de android que tengo que realizar para un proyecto de fin de curso. He encontrado la de Yahoo YQL. Pero me gustaría saber si conocéis alguna otra.

Comment: Hola Eduardo. Esta pregunta, segun lo recogido en el [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), es *basada en opiniones* ya que cada usuario puede recomendar una api u otra. Este tipo de preguntas se cierran ya que no tienen una respuesta exacta que "resuelva tu problema" y puede llevar a debate. Te recomiendo que esperes a tener 20 de reputacion para poder entrar y conversar en la sala de [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) donde las charlas suelen ser más coloquiales y cada uno opina abiertamente. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado a que es un proyecto de fin de curso asumo que debes trabajar con servicios gratuitos, y he dado con los siguientes:

La API de Bloomberg (BLPAPI) es un conjunto de libre disposición kits de desarrollo de software (SDK) que permiten a los desarrolladores de software crear aplicaciones que consumen los datos del mercado.
https://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/

Xignite ofrece un servicio Web SOAP para acceder a cotizaciones de la bolsa de Nueva York (NYSE) y del NASDAQ.
http://www.xignite.com/market-data/market-data-cloud-for-developers/

Forex también ofrece su API, y cuentan con un ejemplo "Android Rates Sample" segun una de las imagenes que aparecen en este link.
https://www.oanda.com/lang/es/forex-trading/platform/api-platform

Saludos, y espero que termines muy bien tu proyecto

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información en un principio no me hacia la idea de la cantidad de API bursatiles que hay en la red. Gracias por compartir esa información con la comunidad